# Engine Overfilled w/additional 5 qts oil

Tags: engine

2011 Dodge Grand Caravan Crew
The dealership confirmed they overfilled my engine oil with an additional 5 qts. After the initial oil change, my vehicle started jerking, shifting hard & overheating with loss of power. I drove about 20 miles before checking my oil. I didn't think I had to inspect the work of the dealership's service center.
he dealership corrected the level, but I'm still experiencing hard shifting & jerking, trouble shifting & loss of power.
After a test drive when i took it back again, the service foreman stated that it could be the shifting strategies & patterns that were affected due to too much oil. He said he reset the patterns, and the transmission was excellent, but problems still exist. 
Before leaving,  they tried to have me sign a release of claims Doc. I refused & still having the same troubles I had when my engine was overfilled. 
I was told that they think a service tech refilled my oil, but then another  came & did the same, but didn't check levels before or after adding more oil.
Could the problems I'm having be caused by the overfilled oil? What damage could have been done?

Comment: The transmission oil is usually separate to the engine oil - so did they drain some out of the transmission or overfill that as well?

Comment: No, but when i did take my vehicle in, the service foreman stated that "the shifting statagies got messed up when we over filled it and it grabbed new shifting patterns". The transmission testing good, but the shifting is loud and off. He did connect it while drive saying he would reset it as it was when it was new. It ran smooth on our test drive back, but it started again when i got on the freeway & progressing as time goes on  again.